# Continuity of diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra

It is known that inverse of a matrix is a continuous function. Could diagonalization of a matrix be considered a continuous function as well?

Comment: What happens in the neighborhood of a non-diagonalisable matrix ?

Comment: It needs lots of precisations, but yes, it is continuous

Comment: You have to be a little careful as similar diagonal matrices are not actually unique (you can rearrange the diagonal entries). If you concentrate on real symmetric matrices, then you can conventionally arrange the eigenvalues in the diagonal in decreasing order. In this case, the map is continuous, and indeed, in each diagonal entry, the scalar-valued map is difference convex, implying the map is locally-Lipschitz (slightly stronger than continuity).

Comment: 'continuous function' is problematic for non hermitian matrices as the eigenvalues are cannot even be a continuous function on $\mathbb C$ -- ref the square root and complex slit plane.